# GET запрос с файлом в Body

Tags: asp.net, http

Есть aspx страничка (ниже часть кода разметки)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" form method="GET">
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="f"/></p>;
    </div>
```

Можно ли сделать так , что бы при GET запросе , файл , выбранный в input, пошёл в REQUEST BODY  запроса?
P.s т.е что бы файл пошёл в GET запросе аналогично POST запросу. P.s.s знаю что наличие body у GET запроса - нарушение спецификации HTTP 1.1.

Comment: в теории, никто не мешает включить в запрос get тело. Но на практике придется слишком много "поплясать". К примеру, фаервол может просто отсечь тело (и будет прав!). Также нужно будет настроить сервер, что бы он это все корректно обработал, а в случае дотнета я не уверен, что это возможно.

Comment: Зачем Вам эти извращения? Расскажите, чем Вас POST не устроил? Особенность бэкэнда?

Comment: Нет , это учебное задание , попытка объяснить что так не стоит делать ни к чему не привела.